# Elasticsearch divide cluster or not

Tags: elasticsearch, devops

I have a cluster consisting of 4 data and 1 master node
each node has:
cpu: 4
ram: 16
and we have 1 largest index of 215 gigabytes (1 primary and 1 replica shard)
on peak days, this index is very heavily loaded (we use aggregation queries, since the index is used to store and send notifications to users), which negatively affects the operation of the entire cluster
the developers propose to allocate a separate cluster for this index, and I propose to add 3 more machines to the cluster and use shard allocation awareness only for this index and divide it into 3 primary and 1 replica shard
what do you think this is right approach? or what is the best way to do it in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

215 gigabytes in a single primary shard is clearly not optimal and most probably the cause of your issues.

The official recommendation is to [not store more than 10GB to 50GB per shard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#shard-size-recommendation), so you should split your index at least to 4 shards.

Then, if your index is loaded because of writes, then you should make sure to allocate each primary shard to each of your data node, so that all writes can happen in parallel on all four data nodes. If the index is loaded because of searches, it doesn't really matter where the primaries and replicas reside, but with big indexes it's always best to spread the load as evenly as possible among all the computing power you have.